# SQLCMD connection error

Tags: sql-server, localhost, sqlcmd

I can successfully connect to my local server from SQL Management Studio, but when I try to connect from *sqlcmd*, there is an error: "**Login failed for user 'my_username'**".

I have checked my username and password - I can login with them in SQL Management Studio.

**P.S.**
  I think that there is a problem in configuration of MS SQL, cause I can't connect to local server with "(local)" name and allways connect to it with COMP\COMP (COMP is my computer name). How can I correct it?

sqlcmd works when I connect to my team *network* server

Comment: Can you show your connection string?

Comment: @PaulGrimshaw, I try connect to server with 'sqlcmd -S COMP -U user_name -P password'

Comment: Try replacing COMP with COMP\COMP

Comment: @DaveK I have already tried COMP\COMP, but things even worse with it : sqlcmd can't find server with this name( "Error locating Server/Instance Specified" ), but in sql management studio COMP\COMP is OK

Comment: When connecting through SSMS can you use (local)\COMP ?

Comment: Try 'sqlcmd -S (local)\COMP -U user_name -P password' or 'sqlcmd -S .\COMP -U user_name -P password'

Comment: @DaveK the same error: "Error locating Server/Instance Specified" with both requests

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30838/discussion-between-dave-k-and-ihar-krasnik)

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem, in the comment there is the solution by @Dave K

```
sqlcmd -S (local)\COMP -U user_name -P password
```

or

```
sqlcmd -S .\COMP -U user_name -P password
```

Hope it helps someone